# How to Compile and Run Everytime I use CodeRunner in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been using **Code Runner** extension to build and run c++, python, and java files in Visual Studio Code. But it doesn't actually compile the program every time I run it. It just **Run** the program. So, If I make any change, The output in the terminal doesn't get updated and doesn't show the changes I have made. The Code Runner just **build** the program **once** and that's it. What should I do to make "Code Runner" **Build or Compile** the program every time I run a program using **"Run"** or **Ctrl+Alt+N**?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Here is what I did to solve the problem.

Go to **Extension Settings** of Code Runner Find and Mark `Save File Before Run`.

[Screnshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4knb.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you are talking about, Go to the top menu and find performance, inside look for an option something like code runner run in the terminal, check that box and then you can give input to the program.